# Flutter say that my cmake must to be (at least) on the version 3.23, but Im using 3.28

Tags: flutter, windows, cmake

*Look, I know, there is some other questions in Stack Overflow with this problem, but no one has the same problem...*

**The problem:**
When I run "flutter run", the result is:

```
Connected devices:
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.3992]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.224
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.133
[1]: Windows (windows)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
[3]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (or "q" to quit): 1    
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in
Building Windows application...
symlinks/record_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.23 or higher is required.  You 
are running version
  3.20.21032501-MSVC_2
Building Windows application...
```

and crashes...

**Ok... but Actually no**
When I run "cmake --version", the result is:

```
cmake version 3.28.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I HAVE THE RIGHT VERSION!!!

**Details**
Flutter doctor summary:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run
flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on
    Microsoft Windows [versÆo
    10.0.19045.3992], locale pt-BR)      
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of    Windows is version 10 or higher)     
[X] Android toolchain - develop for      
    Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.      
      Install Android Studio from:       
      https://developer.android.com/studi      o/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you 
      in installing the Android SDK      
      components.
      (or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-starte      d/install/windows#android-setup for      detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been        
      installed to a custom location,    
      please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to  
      update to that location.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    (Visual Studio Community 2019        
    16.11.32)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)       
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Yes, I tried "flutter clean"
Yes, I also tried reinstall cmake

Comment: first, do not use CAPITAL LETTERS; it is considered rude and feels like you are shouting. Other than that, it is obvious that flutter is not using the CMake you have on a path. My guess is that it is using the CMake shipped with VS

Comment: oh, sorry about the capital letters... in Brazil, we use it sometimes.
but about the answer, thanks!!

Comment: np, :) regarding the answer, I just identified the problem. You might try searching how to force flutter to use system_installed cmake. Good luck!!